# Launching Spyder with multiple versions of Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, anaconda, spyder

I have python 2.7 as my base. I have created an environment with python 3.7.

`conda create -n py3 python=3.7`

in Anaconda Prompt.
Now I have activated my python 3.7.

```
conda activate py3 or activate py3
```

Now I have checked my python version with

```
python --version
```

Its states as  python 3.7.7

```
conda run spyder
```

Now the spyder is launched but it is still opening in python 2.7.

I want to use PyTorch but also need python 2.7 and PyTorch is not suitable to work with python 2.7. I needed to work with PyTorch in python 3.7 and I need python 2.7 also in a single system. How can I do it? Environment setup is ok but the launching of spyder is my real issue.

Comment: I am not an expert, but if this sounds like something you need: `Provides Jupyter kernels for use with the consoles of Spyder, the Scientific Python Development Environment. These can launched either through Spyder itself or in an independent Python session, and allow for interactive or file-based execution of Python code in different environments, all inside the IDE. For more on Spyder, visit https://www.spyder-ide.org/` have a look at spyder-kernels.

Comment: After activating python 3.7 I have installed Pytorch but when I open Jupyter Notebook or Spyder and try to write code with Pytorch(import torch) it gives an error of "No module named Pytorch". I assumed my problem is with the python version as Pytorch is not supported with python 2.7. My spyder or Jupiter notebook is opening with python 2.7 irrespective of my py3 environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type the following in Anaconda Prompt:

```
conda create --name py2 Python=2.7
```

It will create a virtual environment with Python 2.7

```
activate py2
```

To run the spyder with the Python version of 2, the command has to be

```
conda run spyder
```

To deactivate the virtual environment:

```
conda deactivate
```

Same goes for virtual environment with Python 3

```
conda create --name py3 Python=3.7
activate py3
conda run spyder
conda deactivate
```